# Installing separate+ plug-in to GIMP 2.8, help me resolve an error.

Tags: libraries, gimp, color-management

I want to use the separate+ plug-in for GIMP, running GIMP2.8.16 on xUbuntu_16.04. 
I downloaded the zip-file from [sourceforge here](https://osdn.net/projects/separate-plus/releases/p8879). (I chose version 0.5.8, the lower one).

The readme that comes with this specifies, that Littlecms, libtiff and libjpegs dev-versions are required. 
So I installed packages: liblcms2-dev (liblcms2-2 was already available), and libtiff5 + libtiff5-dev, as well as libjpeg8 + libjpeg8-dev through Synaptic package manager.

However when I now try to follow installation instructions via terminal, using the Makefile, I get the following  error:

```
$ make
gcc -g `pkg-config gimp-2.0 --cflags` `pkg-config gimpui-2.0 --cflags` `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags` `pkg-config lcms --cflags` -DENABLE_COLOR_MANAGEMENT -DENABLE_NLS -DGETTEXT_PACKAGE="\"gimp20-separate\"" -DUSE_ICC_BUTTON -c separate-core.c
Package lcms was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `lcms.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'lcms' found
In file included from platform.h:4:0,
                 from separate-core.c:32:
lcms_wrapper.h:13:18: fatal error: lcms.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden (translates to "file or directory not found")
compilation terminated.
Makefile:115: die Regel für Ziel „separate-core.o“ scheiterte (translates to: "rule for target "separate-core.o" failed")
make: *** [separate-core.o] Error 1
```

It seems there's still something missing from LittleCMS, I can find neither a file called "lcms.h" nor "lcms.pc" on my system.

I am still kind of a newbie on Linux and would be really glad if you could help me resolve this issue. I tried to provide any relevant information, if you need more please tell me and add a clue on how to acquire it.

Answer (score 1):

These kind of errors usually mean that you have to install **foo-dev** packages.
In this case try installing **liblcms2-dev**.
There will probably be other errors of this kind after you got that. Just search for the basename of the missing header (in this case "lcms") in Synaptic and install any -dev package that sounds similar.

EDIT: It seems seperate+ 0.5.8 wants liblcms1(-dev). That was removed between 14.04 and 16.04 in favor of version 2. You could try downloading the [packages from trusty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/liblcms1-dev). May work, may not work or could get messy.

Comment: I tried following your suggestions. Having installed all packages that sound similar to liblcms and the respecitve -dev packages I retried installing separate+ and still get the same error. **liblcms2-dev** was even installed when I first encountered the problem. Can you clarify what **foo-dev** packages are and how to get them?

Comment: foo is a generic placeholder, see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar]. I don't know what other missing libraries it could complain about, but the procedure is always similar, you likely need somelibrary-dev.

Comment: Taking a closer look at separate+, maybe 0.5.8 just does not compile under current Ubuntu, it is from 2010. That's ages in the FLOSS world. I can't say how extensive the required changes to the code would need to be to make it compatible. But since there is a newer version available, maybe you're better off trying that.

Your reasoning for not picking the alpha in the first place is sound. In this case however, you may have no other choice.

Comment: Unfortunately the 0.5.9-alpha version is producing the same error. I tried with the alpha version originally, and only then reverted to 0.5.8 as a hopefully stable version. Now I have retried with the alpha, as I installed a few more libraries in the meantime, but it is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the Makefile is able to use lcms2, but uses version 1 by default.  On Ubuntu 16.04, I installed lcms2-dev, and changed the flag in the Makefile:

```
$ diff Makefile~ Makefile
3c3
< #USE_LCMS2 = yes
---
> USE_LCMS2 = yes
```

I also got an error about "separate-core.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pow@@GLIBC_2.2.5'", which was solved by linking the math library:

```
$ diff Makefile~ Makefile
40c40
< LIBS    = $(GIMP_LIB) $(GTK_LIB) $(LCMS_LIB) $(TIFF_LIB) $(JPEG_LIB)
---
> LIBS    = $(GIMP_LIB) $(GTK_LIB) $(LCMS_LIB) $(TIFF_LIB) $(JPEG_LIB) -lm
```